# selecting only records which are not present in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a mysql table1 with `hostname` field and the following values:

```
HostName
-----
sa77.com
ca77cded.com
sa65yacd.com
ca65zededs.com
sa88y.com
sa99ujk8.com
```

I have another table2 which has `name` field(carries hostname values).

```
Name
-----
sa77
ca77cded.com
sa65yacd
ca65zededs.com
```

I want to select records from table2 which are not present in table1

```
select * 
from table2 
where name NOT IN (select hostname from table1);
```

The server name within `name` or `hostname` in either of 2 tables may or maynot be fully qualified. 
For example, `sa77` can have value as `sa77.abc.com` or `sa77.cde` or `sa77`. The server can have multiple domain values

`sa77.abc.com` matches `sa77` and `sa77.abc` I basically need to compare for the value `sa77`

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Are you just wanting to know how to make this work with a JOIN?

Comment: the issue is that in table1 `hostname` value can be `sa77.com` or `sa77` I want to check both the values

Comment: what mean `FQDN for severs` ??

Comment: in the given example it looks like table1 always has .com and table2 may or may not. please clarify.

Comment: i have edited my question. The server name within `name` or `hostname` in either of 2 tables may or maynot be fully qualified.

Comment: so `sa77.abc.com` match `sa77` and `sa77.abc` ??

Comment: yes this correct. `sa77.abc.com` matches `sa77` and `sa77.abc` I basically need to check for the value `sa77`

Comment: sa77 or in general any "domain" name?I guess the second as would be more general.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do this using a `left join` and a `where is null`, like this:

```
select * 
from table2
left join table1 on table2.name=table1.hostname
where table1.hostname is null;
```

(edit because you want records from table2 not in table1, rather than the reverse.)

Comment: This indeed should be the most effient way as from this https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Agreed--it yields the correct results and is more efficient than using CONCAT as suggested in other examples.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
where name NOT IN (select hostname from table1)
  and CONCAT(name, '.com') NOT IN (select hostname from table1);
```

But you need explain a litle more about what cases you need to match.

Comment: i have edited my question. The server name within name or hostname in either of 2 tables may or maynot be fully qualified